# Python is decoding my Base64-String into a false String-Representation

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, windows, utf-8

I have the following C# Code to create a Base64-String out of a String with german Umlauts:

```
var file = @"C:\Work\Podcast\Gehör\Folgen\2023-08-08 11-05-01.mkv";
var filePathBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file);
var encodedFilePathString = Convert.ToBase64String(filePathBytes);
```

I am then giving it over to Python to do some work on this video file with specific python modules like so:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = "cmd",
    Arguments = $"/c cd {ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PythonScriptPath"]} & {ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PythonFilePath"]} -c \"import MyModule; MyModule.doWork('{encodedFilePathString}')\"",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true
};
```

And on Python-side I am (for now) trying to output the String to see how the encoding works:

```
decodedFileName = base64.b64decode(encodedVideoFilePath).decode('utf-8')

the_encoding = chardet.detect(base64.b64decode(encodedVideoFilePath))['encoding']
print(the_encoding, flush=True)

print(encodedVideoFilePath, flush=True)
print(decodedFileName, flush=True)
print(os.path.exists(decodedFileName), flush=True)
```

And the Python-Output looks as following:

```
Received from standard out: ISO-8859-9
Received from standard out: QzpcV29ya1xQb2RjYXN0XEdlaMO2clxGb2xnZW5cMjAyMy0wOC0wOCAxMS0wNS0wMS5ta3Y=
Received from standard out: C:\Work\Podcast\Geh÷r\Folgen\2023-08-08 11-05-01.mkv
Received from standard out: True
Received from standard out:
```

(This output is from my Process-Console and thus prefixed with "Received from standard out:")

The only real thing is here that the string of the MKV-File isn't correctly displayed. In the Print-Output and somewhere down the road in the python code where I would need the string to be inserted somewhere else but this `÷`-Char is still there.

But Python can find the File even with this falsy encoding. So what should I do to handle this UTF-8 encoded string correctly?

Comment: _But Python can find the File even with this falsy encoding_, possibly it is just a display error in the terminal/shell you are using ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer `In the Print-Output and somewhere down the road in the python code where I would need the string to be inserted somewhere else but this ÷-Char is still there.`

Comment: `>>> print(base64.b64decode('QzpcV29ya1xQb2RjYXN0XEdlaMO2clxGb2xnZW5cMjAyMy0wOC0wOCAxMS0wNS0wMS5ta3Y=').decode('utf-8'))`, this is what I get on a Mac: `C:\Work\Podcast\Gehör\Folgen\2023-08-08 11-05-01.mkv`

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I am working on Windows (I have added the Windows-Tag just now)

Comment: Using the line Maurice posted, works for me too, using Windows10 and Python3.6

Comment: @MafMal Yes. In CMD-Prompt this works for me too. But not in this C#-Process environment.

Comment: In a Turkish environment (guessed from `ISO-8859-9`), you face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `'Gehör'.encode( 'cp1254').decode( 'cp857')` returns `'Geh÷r'`. Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)… Using the line Maurice posted, works for me too, using Windows10 and Python3.11.

Comment: Issue could be you are using the wrong font to display the character.  You need a German Font to display the character.